# MATLAB - Plotting lines in different colours according to comparible z value

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, cell, octave

I am using some MATLAB code to track particles in a fluid solution via video capture.

All the particles tracked are stored in an array of cells (`tr`) with each cell entry being a different particle tracked. The cell then contains an `N x 11` matrix where each row contains the parameters of the particle at that particular frame (position, size, contrast etc.) and N is the number of video frames the particle has been tracked for.

Column 1 of each cell contains the particles x-position, Column 2 of each cell contains the particles y-position, Column 11 of each cell contains the particles mean speed across all frames captured (ignore all the other columns).

An example for a particle cell:

[image: Example of typical particle cell]

Now typically to plot these tracks over the first frame of the video I have captured I use the following code:

```
image = read(mmreader([movie '.avi']), 1);  %Loads the first frame of the avi file
figure
imshow(image);
hold on
for i = 1:length(tr) % Or choose which particle you want to show
plot3(tr{i}(:,1),tr{i}(:,2),tr{i}(:,11),'r')
end
```

But what I would prefer to do is plot the particles as I would using the code above but have the colour of the particle track dependant on the value of its mean speed (red - fast, blue - slow etc..). I thought maybe the best way to do this would be to plot it in 3D and use the mean speed as the Z-axis value? But I'm still unsure for here how to add the colour to the plot and keep it relative so the speeds of different particles can be compared by the colour they are plotted in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to first decide for each track where in the color range you want to be. (For example calculate the speed of each track)

After this you can `sort` the tracks to get them in the right order.

Then you can use a `colormap` to make sure that each line will get the right color.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give a look to the FEX package [cline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14677-cline).

Consider this example (2D curve whose color is determined by its speed)

```
tt = 0:.1:5

x_v = sin(tt);y_v = tt.^2;                % // my curve

speed = sqrt( cos(tt).^2 + (2 * tt).^2 ); % // its local speed
figure
cline(x_v,y_v,speed);
```

[image]

It works in 3D also, therefore you can put `speed` as a third coordinate as you were thinking.